# Make Vue interpret components that have been inserted programmatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

I'd like to modify a `div` inside my Vue component's template using the [Rangy library](https://github.com/timdown/rangy). I have code like this in one of my methods:

```
let tooltip = document.createElement('button');
tooltip.setAttribute('type', 'button');
tooltip.setAttribute('v-tooltip.top-center', '"msg"');
tooltipSpan.innerHTML = 'x';

// Insert span with tooltip after of mistake
range.collapse(false);
range.insertNode(tooltipSpan);
```

As you can see in the third line, I also want to use a [v-tooltip](https://akryum.github.io/v-tooltip) component. If I could hardcode this inside the template, it'd simply be `<button v-tooltip.top-center="msg">x</button>`. But in my app, this component could be programmatically placed anywhere inside a div, so I need to insert it with JavaScript. There might also be more than one instance of that component.

Unfortunately, my approach does not work at all. It doesn't matter whether I use the approach mentioned above using the `v-tooltip` directive or if I simply insert a component (e.g., `let tooltip = document.createElement('my-custom-tooltip');`): The new DOM element is correctly inserted, but Vue does not recognize/interpret it as a component. In the above example, all I get is a simple, unstyled button element.

I tried `this.$forceUpdate()`, `this.$nextTick()` and a bunch of older methods (that have probably vanished from Vue 2), but nothing worked.

Is there a way to make Vue re-render after manual changes to he DOM, correctly interpreting components that have been inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Vue "owns" the DOM tree belonging to any component; if you mess around in the DOM like you are, any Vue-specific things that you create or modify (like directives) won't magically work.

The DOM that is generated by Vue is a function of the component's data; any time the data changes Vue will re-render the DOM to reflect that change. Vue doesn't know how to deal with manual changes you make to the DOM.

I don't know specifically what you are trying to do and why Rangy is needed, but the correct way to do something like this would be to modify your *data* not the DOM, and then your template (or render function) takes care of rendering the new data.

> Is there a way to make Vue re-render after manual changes to he DOM, **correctly interpreting components that have been inserted?**

No.

Comment: Thanks. I do things like this: 1) Go through all objects in `this.ranges`. 2) For every range, highlight a certain part of text insert a certain `div` (This is done by Rangy, it inserts a new span with a certain class according to the ranges `start` and `end` properties. This part is working. 3) Insert a small popover component at the end of each range (I say _popover_ because eventually I'll need something clickable). Is there a way to do this without manipulation the DOM directly? I'm afraid `v-for`, which is typically used in examples, won't help me.